# SQL server mail function sp_send_cdontsmail

Tags: sql, sql-server

i wrote a procedure in which i tried to send mail using below command.

```
EXEC Sp_send_cdontsmail 'from','to','Test','TEST DATA'
```

After executing its showing "Command(s) completed successfully."

but i am not getting any mail.please help me on this.

Comment: Have you updated the sproc w/ your SMTP server? Also this is probably dumb but you aren't literally putting in from and to right? You just put that in as test data...

Comment: Ya store procedure is already in server. And this from and to value i just put dummy value.

Comment: You need to update the SPROC w/ your SMTP server. Right now it probably just has a dummy value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure [Database Mail](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175887%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and then use [`sp_send_dbmail`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx) to send mail. This is a supported procedure, part of the SQL Server.

PS. I am aware that out there some code sample circulates that advocates something along the lines of:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_send_cdontsmail] 
...
EXEC @hr = master..sp_OACreate 'CDONTS.NewMail', @MailID OUT 
EXEC @hr = master..sp_OASetProperty @MailID, 'From',@From 
EXEC @hr = master..sp_OASetProperty @MailID, 'Body', @Body
...
```

This is horrible code. As one can easily see there is absolutely 0 (zero, nada, zip) error checking in this code. Any failure will be reported as 'success'. COM interop will not raise T-SQL notification messages, is all in the HRESULT, which goes unchecked. Steer away from such code.

Comment: To use database mail don't you have to install outlook or something similar? Just a good note to raise if it is true...

Comment: No, Database Mail is standalone.

Comment: The procedure [sp_send_cdontsmail] is already there. any other configuration need to be done. because i am not getting error message while executing the procedure.